# Interrupt masking: why?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, interrupt

I was reading up on interrupts. It is possible to suspend non-critical interrupts via a special interrupt mask. This is called interrupt masking. What i dont know is when/why you might want to or need to temporarily suspend interrupts? Possibly Semaphores, or programming in a multi-processor environment?

Comment: my limited understanding is that you typically want to do this inside critical sections of driver code - to ensure an "atomic" operation is not interrupted.

Comment: Is it to me or the `c++` tag isn't very relevant for the question?

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu: agreed. It's more related to Operating Systems anyway. Retagged.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The OS does that when it prepares to run its own "let's orchestrate the world" code.

For example, at some point the OS thread scheduler has control. It prepares the processor registers and everything else that needs to be done before it lets a thread run so that the environment for that process and thread is set up. Then, before letting that thread run, it sets a timer interrupt to be raised after the time it intends to let the thread have on the CPU elapses.

After that time period (quantum) has elapsed, the interrupt is raised and the OS scheduler takes control again. It has to figure out what needs to be done next. To do that, it needs to save the state of the CPU registers so that it knows how to undo the side effects of the code it executes. If another interrupt is raised for any reason (e.g. some async I/O completes) while state is being saved, this would leave the OS in a situation where its world is *not* in a valid state (in effect, saving the state needs to be an atomic operation).

To avoid being caught in that situation, the OS kernel therefore disables interrupts while any such operations that need to be atomic are performed. After it has done whatever needs doing and the system is in a known state again, it reenables interrupts.

Comment: Most modern OSes use re-entrant interrupt handlers that are designed such that they don't corrupt existing state regardless of how many nested interrupts occur -- so the situation of not being in a valid state doesn't arise. As @Tommy answered, priorities are the primary reason why masking is used.

Comment: This answer discusses disabling interrupts (i.e. global masking). It doesn't address the original question about "suspend[ing] non-critical interrupts via a special interrupt mask."

Comment: Wikipedia says that global interrupt masks has many problems including stopping the world on multi-processor systems, and clock drift. Is global interrupt masks still used on uni-processor and multi-processor situations for OSes like Linux/Windows/BSD?

Comment: Keil RTX calims no interrupt block-out through the entire kernel running scope, I wonder how does it implement

Answer (score 16):

I used to program on an ARM board that had about 10 interrupts that could occur. Each particular program that I wrote was never interested in more than 4 of them. For instance there were 2 timers on the board, but my programs only used 1. I would mask the 2nd timer's interrupt. If I didn't mask that timer, it might have been enabled and continued making interrupts which would slow down my code.

Another example was that I would use the UART receive REGISTER full interrupt and so would never need the UART receive BUFFER full interrupt to occur.

I hope this gives you some insight as to why you might want to disable interrupts.

Comment: Thanks for sharing real world programming examples.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to answers already given, there's an element of priority to it. There are some interrupts you need or want to be able to respond to as quickly as possible and others you'd like to know about but only when you're not so busy. The most obvious example might be refilling the write buffer on a DVD writer (where, if you don't do so in time, some hardware will simply write the DVD incorrectly) versus processing a new packet from the network. You'd disable the interrupt for the latter upon receiving the interrupt for the former, and keep it disabled for the duration of filling the buffer.

In practise, quite a lot of CPUs have interrupt priority built directly into the hardware. When an interrupt occurs, the disabled flags are set for lesser interrupts and, often, that interrupt at the same time as reading the interrupt vector and jumping to the relevant address. Dictating that receipt of an interrupt also implicitly masks that interrupt until the end of the interrupt handler has the nice side effect of loosening restrictions on interrupting hardware. E.g. you can simply say that signal high triggers the interrupt and leave the external hardware to decide how long it wants to hold the line high for without worrying about inadvertently triggering multiple interrupts.

In many antiquated systems (including the z80 and 6502) there tends to be only two levels of interrupt — maskable and non-maskable, which I think is where the language of enabling or disabling interrupts comes from. But even as far back as the original 68000 you've got eight levels of interrupt and a current priority level in the CPU that dictates which levels of incoming interrupt will actually be allowed to take effect.

Comment: +1 for mentioning priorities. I was just writing about this, wondering why nobody mentioned it yet.

Comment: If an interrupt is a disabled, is it just ignored and dropped, or is queued in some way?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai depends on the architecture and the interrupting device — some interrupts signal for a particular period of time then automatically resolve themselves whether the CPU acts or not, probably most continue to assert until the CPU deals with them. It generally depends on what they're trying to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your CPU is in "int3" handler now and at that time "int2" happens and the newly happened "int2" has a lower priority compared with "int3". How would we handle with this situation?

A way is when handling "int3", we are masking out other lower priority interrupters. That is we see the "int2" is signaling to CPU but the CPU would not be interrupted by it. After we finishing handling the "int3", we make a return from "int3" and unmasking the lower priority interrupters.

The place we returned to can be:

1. Another process(in a preemptive system)
2. The process that was interrupted by "int3"(in a non-preemptive system or preemptive system)
3. An int handler that is interrupted by "int3"， say int1's handler.

In cases 1 and 2, because we unmasked the lower priority interrupters and "int2" is still signaling the CPU: "hi, there is a something for you to handle immediately", then the CPU would be interrupted again, when it is executing instructions from a process, to handle "int2"

In case 3, if the priority of “int2” is higher than "int1", then the CPU would be interrupted again, when it is executing instructions from "int1"'s handler, to handle "int2".

Otherwise, "int1"'s handler is executed without interrupting (because we are also masking out the interrupters with priority lower then "int1" ) and the CPU would return to a process after handling the “int1” and unmask. At that time "int2" would be handled.