# Why InputStream in JAVA ignore interrupt

Tags: java, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I have read  something about [interrupt mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917205/interrupt-masking-why),OS need to save it's state when another thread need to run ,if there is no interrupt mask,a thread interrupt occur when OS save the state, OS may can not save success . is this relate to 'InputStream ' in java not design to response to interrupt? and why?

Comment: CPU interrupts and Java thread interrupts are two completely separate mechanisms.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout